# Ubuntu 12.04 - Grub1 won't load new kernel

Tags: ubuntu, vps, ubuntu-12.04, kernel, grub

For some reason I can't get grub to load the new kernel.

I tried removing the old kernels with aptitude and running `update-grub` but it still loads the old kernel - even though I've removed it!

I then manually updated the grub config file (/boot/grub/menu.lst) and restarted but still no joy.

#### Commands run to try to get grub to update:

```
$ sudo aptitude remove linux-image-3.2.0-23-virtual
$ sudo aptitude remove linux-image-3.2.0-24-virtual # ..etc up to 3.2.0-49

$ sudo update-grub

$ sed -i 's/3.2.0-23/3.2.0-49/ig' /boot/grub/menu.lst

$ sudo reboot
```

#### Current state of system:

```
$ grub --version
grub (GNU GRUB 0.97)

$ uname -r
3.2.0-23-virtual

$ cat /boot/grub/menu.lst | grep 3.2.0-49
title vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-virtual
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-virtual root=LABEL=root ro
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-virtual

$ cat /boot/grub/menu.lst | grep 3.2.0-23
# <nothing>

$ ls -l /boot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  795318 Jun 18 18:39 abi-3.2.0-49-virtual
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140637 Jun 18 18:39 config-3.2.0-49-virtual
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul 27 10:03 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5788488 Jul 26 17:49 initrd.img-3.2.0-49-virtual
-rw------- 1 root root 2892052 Jun 18 18:39 System.map-3.2.0-49-virtual
-rw------- 1 root root 4964112 Jun 18 18:39 vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-virtual
```

This was the first time I was prompted to update the kernel by apt via email. So it looks like the previous unattended upgrades that installed kernels failed to update grub either.

I'd prefer not to risk updating to grub 2 as this is a VPS and I won't have supergrubdisk to save me if something goes haywire.

Comment: Which virtualization technology is this?

Comment: It's KVM virtualization being used.

Comment: Hmm. And who is your provider?

Comment: It's digital ocean. You were right that was the problem. The only way to upgrade is through their control panel I just [discovered](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/do-you-update-kernels-sometimes). Thanks a lot for putting me on to the solution.

Comment: Yep, it's one of Digital Ocean's biggest mistakes. And why I don't use them anymore. Feel free to post it as your own answer.

Comment: Who did you move to out of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be my hosting provider, Digital Ocean.

The only solution for Digital Ocean customers is to [upgrade via the panel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/do-you-update-kernels-sometimes).